# Tensorflow throw "model_dir should be non-empty"

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, quickdraw

I am going over tensorflow tutrial for RNN of drawings: 
*https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/recurrent_quickdraw*

But I stuck to executing the command:

```
train_model.py \
    --training_data=rnn_tutorial_data/training.tfrecord-00000-of-00010 \
    --eval_data=rnn_tutorial_data/eval.tfrecord-00000-of-00010 \
    --classes_file=rnn_tutorial_data/training.tfrecord.classes
```

**Tensorflow throws:**

> model_dir should be non-empty

**and It still happens after I add:**

```
--model_dir=modeldir
```

Comment: Does `modeldir` contain the model?

Comment: No. From where I get the model? it's not mentiond in the tutorial.

Comment: Does `modeldir` exist on your machine?

Comment: You should make a directory named 'modeldir'.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, so just make a new directory say 'model_dir' and mention this by flag

```
--model_dir=model_dir
```

Answer (score 1):

this is referring to --output-dir, had this issue when the --output-dir was not local, but /home/me/etc/etc